# Automatic file checker

Tags: file, networking, automation

I have a public folder on windows, that people use for file transfers between computers, temporary storage, etc.  Sometimes, people send me stuff in that file and I want to automaticaly know when.  I want to automaticaly check the folder for any new or changed files, then display a message telling the name, date, and size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout this list of monitoring tools: http://www.raymond.cc/blog/3-portable-tools-monitor-files-folders-changes/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an app that uses a timer and checks every x milliseconds if a new file has been copied to the specified file. I can develop this app for you for the price of just 35 EUR.